# Injecting data acces layer class in to business layer class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am in a process of moving all business logic codes to business layer class from my controller in .net MVC4 project. So I need to access data access layer class from business layer. File structure is like this.

Controller

```
private readonly ICandidateRepository _candidateRepository;
private readonly IJobApplyService _jobApplyService;
public CandidateController(ICandidateRepository candidateRepository, IJobApplyService jobApplyService
{
  _candidateRepository = candidateRepository;
  _jobApplyService = jobApplyService;
}
```

Business Layer

```
private readonly ICandidateRepository _candidateRepository;
public JobApplyService(ICandidateRepository candidateRepository)
{
        _candidateRepository= candidateRepository;
}
```

Data Access Class

```
CandidateRepository
```

I can achieve this by using Ninject DI. but problem is in my controller 2 instances of CandidateRepository data access class are created for each HTTP request.

How can I prevent that?

Are there any other good approach for this?

Comment: How is the `ICandidateRepository` configured for dependency injection? If it's per-request, I would think the same instance would be shared between the controller and the business layer. However, I would recommend not directly access the repository in the controller at all. Since you have business layer services, those will ideally be the middle man between the controller and data layer.

Comment: @MattU ICandidateRepository  is configured to use per request. could u tell me how to share the same instance between controller and business layer?

Comment: they should already be sharing an instance then. You are indeed injecting it into two different classes, but I believe they both ultimately reference the same shared instance for any given request.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the code in interface declaration

```
private readonly ICandidateRepository _candidateRepository;
public JobApplyService(CandidateRepository candidateRepository)
{
        _candidateRepository= candidateRepository;
}
```

both the place controller and business layer

"CandidateRepository candidateRepository"

Comment: Accepting a concrete implementation creates coupling, in this case, between `JobApplyService` and `CandidateRepository`. Also, this answer is not addressing what the questions is asking.

Comment: How this answer solves my problem. I don't understand.